# Using 'Done' instead of 'Success' in Angular promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

I've got an issue where I'm using the Contentful.js library to retrieve content in an Angular app. Instead of the normal `$http.get` with the `success(data)` callback, it uses a function with `done(data)`. I can set the `$scope.lists` value to the returned data, but it does not show up in the HTML for some reason.

This works for a detail view using the standard `$http`:

```
$http.get('https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/xxxxxxx/entries?sys.id=' + $routeParams.listId + '&include=10&access_token=xxxxxxxx').success (data) ->
            $scope.list = data
            console.log $scope.list
```

This doesn't work for a list view using the `done()` method:

```
client = contentful.createClient
        accessToken: 'xxxxxxxx'
        space: 'xxxxxxxxx'

listControllers.controller('ListListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', ($scope, $http) ->
    $scope.lists = ""
    client.entries({'content_type': 'xxxxxxxx', 'include': 1}).done (data) ->
        $scope.lists = data
        console.log $scope.lists
])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably since this library is not targetted towards AngularJS, it is not doing `$scope.$apply()` to trigger digest cycle and hence the html is not getting updated.

The fix would be wrap the assingment done in callback with `$scope.$apply()`.The JavaScript fix for this would be

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
   $scope.lists = data
});
```

Since i have not use this library i may be wrong here with `done` callback implementation.